# core i7 processor - x86-64 , cross compile kernel

Tags: fedora, intel

I would like to know whether all core i7 processor is of type x86_64.(as per wiki it says so)

I have a core i7 machine (from /proc/cpuinfo) where only 32bit kernel in installed on the same.
Also, it has 32 bit gcc compiler installed.

If core i7 supports x86_64 kernel , I would like to install the same. I hope all the 32 bit binaries can run on x86_64 kernel , so I am not going to do anything with applications.

Now, My questions are:

1. whether core i7 supports x86_64?
2. How to install a 64 bit cross compiler in order to build a kernel (64 bit type). My machine is Fedora FC15.
3. I hope all 32 bit apps should work fine with this 64 bit kernel. ?
4. How to get 64 bit cross compiler  for fedora (x86_64)?

Note,  I am aware about cross compiling kernel.

Comment: FC15 is way past it's end of life. You really should move on to a newer version.

Comment: I agree, but even if I upgrade FC15 same issue will exists. I mean If I simply upgrade Fedora, I still need to do the above.

Comment: Think about reinstall.

Comment: sorry...I would like to maintain FC15 due to other reasons...any other suggestions?